# How do I access URL query parameters from a POST request in a Python Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure, http, post, azure-functions

I can't figure out how to access URL query parameters from a POST request in a Python Azure Function. I am locally testing the function on VSCode.

I've tried:

1. req.params.get('paramName') - it always is none
2. url = req.url

   query_parameters = urllib.parse.parse_qs(url.query)

   param = query_parameters.get('paramName', [None])[0]

   - I get the error: url has no query attribute
3. I also tried os.environ as I saw somewhere that params are automatically set as environment variables for azure functions

Comment: req.params.get('paramName') is what works for python. Maybe we can help better if you can update the question with your actual code and the structure of your API URL.

Answer (score 0):

*I am able to get the query parameter using urllib and req.params.get in the following way*

**`Code:`**

```
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  urllib.parse  import  urlparse  

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

#using urllib
query_param=  urlparse(req.url).query.split('=')[1]
print("Query Parameter using Urllib:",query_param)  

name  =  req.params.get('name')
print("Query Parameter using req.params.get:", name)

if  not  name:
try:
req_body  =  req.get_json()
except  ValueError:
pass
else:
name  =  req_body.get('name') 
if  name:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
else:

return  func.HttpResponse(
"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
status_code=200
)
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]